# Evaluating $\sin 10^\circ + \sin 20^\circ + \sin 30^\circ + \cdots +\sin 90^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

> The question is finding
> $$S = \sin 10^\circ + \sin 20^\circ + \sin 30^\circ + \cdots +\sin 90^\circ$$

I tried to do it, but I can't eliminate the $\cos 5^\circ$.

Can anyone help me with the answer?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate $\cos 5^\circ$?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: @AnginaSneg That for finding the ans easily . If you know any altenative method please show me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best it is to follow symbolic derivation of sums of sine of $n$  angles in A.P, of common difference $\beta= 10^{\circ}.$ And then apply it.

$$ S = \sin ( average\; angle)\cdot \dfrac{\sin n \beta/2}{\sin \beta/2}$$

$$={ \sin 50^{\circ}}\dfrac{ \sin 9\times 5^{\circ}}{\sin 5^{\circ}}.$$